# Cannot load MapKit module

Tags: xcode, swift, mapkit

When I do `import MapKit` in Swift like described in the apple documentation.

I get cannot load 'mapKit' as MapKit. I've tried `import mapKit` but that also doesn't work.

Comment: Did you turn on Map in the project's capabilities?

Comment: Yes I did turn it on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I named my project mapKit, so if I import the mapkit framework it gave an error.